# python says apple is not equal to apple

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have an odd situation in my django code, where python refuses to accept that two strings are equal:

```
def depticon(depta):
    print(f'depta is {depta}')
    print(f'Testing |{depta}| against |Ear, Nose, Throat|')
    if depta=="Ear, Nose, Throat":        
        icon = "ear.png"
        print("Matched ENT")
    else:
        print("No match")
        icon = "health-sign.png"
    print(f'Icon is {icon}')
    return icon
```

This is how it is called. Here, clinics is a queryset:

```
specialties = []
specialtytext = []
specialtyicon = []
for clinic in clinics:
    if clinic.doctorid.dept not in specialties:
        dept = clinic.doctorid.department
        specialties.append(dept)
        specialtytext.append(depttext(dept))
        specialtyicon.append(depticon(dept))
```

See the output:

```
depta is Ear, Nose, Throat
Testing |Ear, Nose, Throat| against |Ear, Nose, Throat|
No match
Icon is health-sign.png
```

I put the `|` character around the string to check whether there are any special characters in the string.

Comment: maybe the types of the strings are not same. please print the type of the depta by `print(type(depta))`

Comment: Oops. I didnt think about automatic casting. It was `<class 'appointments.models.Department'>`

Comment: This isn't your question, but why use `clinic.doctorid.dept` in one place, and `clinic.doctorid.department` in another? Why the difference of "dept" vs "department"?

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt I just realized what you meant. That was a mistake. I should have used clinic.doctorid.dept in both places

Comment: You should show your models. Apart from the issue you are seeing, there is certainly a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the type of the `depta` argument is not `str`, and that is why it is not matching the `str` value "Ear, Nose, Throat". Try passing the `department` value to `str()` before using it further.

Fun fact: the `print()` function casts arguments using `str()` automatically.